# Opencart 2.0 - add product direct to cart

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart, opencart2.x

I have recently installed Opencart Ver. 2.1.0.1

What i want is to add products directly from Landing pages (basic HTML/CSS) to cart of Opencart.

Earlier for Opencart version 1.5, i was using a tweak and it was working fine.

Ideally adding   ?route=checkout/cart&add_product=1&product_id[]=170&qty[]=1
after domain name, so add product to the cart.

Any help by Opencart expert will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to change the code according to OC 2.x

Comment: Take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982570/make-add-to-cart-a-link-instead-of-a-button/40996650#40996650

Answer (score 0):

In opencart V2 and upwards the change has been made as follows:

The link is now changed to

`onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>');"`

Where the onclick event triggers the add to cart function with the parameters

1. Product ID - Unique identifier of the product.
2. Minimum - this refers to the quantity being ordered.