# Make 'Add to Cart' a link, instead of a button

Tags: php, opencart

In category.tpl I changed:

```
<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></button>
```

to:

```
<a href="index.php?route=checkout/cart/add&product_id=<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>&quantity=<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>" method="get"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></a>
```

Clicking Add to Cart now loads the page background, with only:

> [ ]

as content.

I am trying to make a 'shareable' link, that when copied (into a newsletter, for example) clicking that link automatically adds the item to your cart.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: What is `cart.add` and what do you have in `index.php`??????

Comment: index.php is the config & constructors for opencart.  cart.add is the javascript function that handles the add to cart action

Comment: Your problem can be in the index.php file.......

Comment: There's no code in index.php. Opencart is MVC-based. `start('catalog');` is the extent of the code in index.php.  This isn't so much of a problem as it is changing behavior.  Out-of-the-box, it works; I'd just like to add more flexibility by allowing the add to cart functionality to be shared without actually having to 'click' add to cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>` is a `javascript` `function` that send product with `ajax` and [**`POST`**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) method to cart.
if you want to do this with a link, so you need to use [**`GET`**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

1) in `category.tpl`, instead of:

```
<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></button>
```

use:

```
<a href="index.php?route=checkout/cart/addToCart&product_id=<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></a>
```

2) open this file:

```
catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php
```

here is a new `function` that works with `GET`, add it to this file:

```
public function addToCart() {
    $this->load->language('checkout/cart');

    if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
        $product_id = (int)$this->request->get['product_id'];
    } else {
        $product_id = 0;
    }

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

    if ($product_info) {
        $this->cart->add($product_id);

        // Display success message
        $this->session->data['success'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_success'), $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->post['product_id']), $product_info['name'], $this->url->link('checkout/cart'));

        //redirect to cart page
        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
    }
}
```

this will send product to cart, though this is a simple function that add product with quantity = 1 and doesn't check the product options, but that's the way it is, you can modify it based on your need.

Now you can share product's add to cart link anywhere. (tested on latest version 2.3.0.2)

Comment: Hey thanks!!  When I test, I get: The page you requested cannot be found! when trying to add a product to my cart

Comment: Which opencart version?

Comment: 2.3.0.2_rc - I tried it on 2.3.0.2 and worked as expected!!  Thanks so much!!  Starting to realize how finnicky a release candidate version with OC is, I've never worked with software where they change so much yet consider it a patch or candidate version; should be 2.4 with how much has changed!  Again, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

keep the link href empty and take the onclick event from the button. i must ask though, why not simply style the button as you wish?

Comment: White this works, you cannot right click on the link to share it.  It has the same behavior as the default button.

Comment: In regards to the styling question; it's not the appearance I am trying to alter, but the functionality.  You cannot "share" the add to cart button as it works out of the box.